# How to repeat the content of an item?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I am trying to repeat the content of an enumerate item.

I tried it with the `nameref` package but without success:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item\label{enu:first}
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}

This is the text of the first list item: \nameref{enu:first}

\end{document}
```

`\nameref{enu:first}` seems to create just an empty string in this case. What I would like it, or some similar command using the label key, to create is "First item".

Comment: by default latex never access all the item text, if you need that it would be easier to have a custom syntax where the item text was in `{...}` as the argument of a command then it would be easier to save. Otherwise you need some slightly tricky code to collect up text to the next following `\item` or `\end{enumerate}`

Comment: Thanks. I think I would prefer the slightly Tricky Code since I could then leave all the other text as it is.